# how to display all images in a folder

Tags: php, html, laravel, codeigniter

I'm develop my websites and want to display all the images in a folder. I used the following code but occurred an error.

```
<?php 
    $sesi = Session::get('id'); 
    $gambar = glob('archive_gambar/formulir/pendaftaran/'.$sesi.'/*'); 
      for ($i=0; $i<count($gambar); $i++) 
      { 
        $single_image = $gambar[$i];
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $single_image; ?>" class="img-responsive" style="margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; margin-top: auto;margin-bottom: auto;width:75%;" alt="Tri">
        <?php
      }
  ?>
```

there is no error, the number of images is the same, but the picture does not appear.. like this
[picture not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpWvT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dirname = "media/images/iconized/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.png");

foreach($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: it still same but when the image is clicked, the address becomes like this.
`http://localhost:8000/gerai_ut/archive_gambar/formulir/pendaftaran/1/1-banner_2.jpg`
why so the controller appears, the name of controller is gerai_ut

Answer (score 0):

If the `archive_gambar` directory is at the root of the web site, try adding slash in front of the path

```php
$gambar = glob('/archive_gambar/formulir/pendaftaran/'.$sesi.'/*');
```

if not, you must write the full path

Comment: where exactly do you save the image file

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, adjust the **$dir** variable to your needs:

```
/**
 * This file: images.php
 * This script read content of  "images" directory as same level, and return filelist in array format
 **/
$dir = "images/";

$images = array();
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            if($dir){
                if(in_array($file, array('.', '..')) == FALSE){
                    $images[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}

/**
 * Print array to browswer
 */
echo '<pre>';
print_r($images);

 /**
  * Iterate $images array in foreach loop and display images with img tag (need to adjust directory to your needs).
  */
foreach ($images as $key => $image){
    echo '<img src="images/'.$image.'" class="img-responsive" alt="image_'.$key.'">';
}
```

Comment: the result is 
`Array
(
    [0] => 1-banner_2.jpg
    [1] => 1-banner_5.jpg
    [2] => 1-dashboard_slides.jpg
    [3] => 1-login_1.jpg
    [4] => 1-login_2.jpg
)`
but the picture is not appear. i see in the adress there is a method from controller `http://localhost:8000/gerai_ut/1-dashboard_slides.jpg`
if gerai_ut is deleted, the picture is appear.
how can i fix this?

Comment: You call the images directly from path o via any controller?

Comment: If your controller is altering the url, I think you should add a rule so that it does not include it as part of the URL, this is only a guess, I don't know how your framework is structured. You can do this with rewrite rules in the .htaccess file of your project.

Comment: You can also try using absolute paths in the image tag /path/to/image.jpg instead of path/to/image.jpg

Comment: Did any of the contributions help you?